# How can you delay your fsm to stay in one of the state for about lets say 5 clock cycle?

Tags: vhdl

If I want to delay my FSM to stay in a state for 5 cycle how could I do that?
I suppose I should use a counter but what is the VHDL code how could I use a counter inside the process statement.

Sorry if the question is simple I am learning VHDL coding.

I am using this coding, but it is not compiling :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity state3_fsm is
  port (
    clk_H  : in std_logic;
    res_H  : in std_logic;
    start  : in std_logic;
    done_H : in std_logic);

end entity state3_fsm;


architecture arc of state3_fsm is

  type statetype is (s0, s1, s2);
  signal pr_state, nx_state : statetype;
  signal count              : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin
  ff_pro : process (clk_H, res_H)

  begin
    if (res_H = '1') then
      pr_state <= s0;
    elsif (clk_H'event and clk_H = '1') then
      pr_state <= nx_state;
    end if;
  end process ff_pro;

  com_pro : process (start, count, pr_state, done_H)
  begin
    case pr_state is

      when s0 =>
        if (start = '1') then
          nx_state <= s1;
        else nx_state <= s0;
        end if;


      when s1 =>
        count <= count + 1;
        if (count = 5) then
          nx_state <= s2;
          count    <= "000";
        else
          nx_state <= s2;

        end if;

      when s2 =>
        if done_H = '1' then
          nx_state <= s0;
        else nx_state <= s2;
        end if;

      when others =>
        nx_state <= s0;

    end case;
  end process com_pro;

end architecture arc;
```

Comment: If you want your exit decision to be different based upon the value of your counter, then your state must in reality be at least TWO states!!

Answer (score 1):

What you have is on the left, and what you want is on the right assuming you want a delay between *State 2* and *State 3*. You simply can add a new state that handles the delay.
[image]

Some pseudo code for the delay state would be implemented like the following:

```
if(clk)
delay_counter <= delay_counter + 1'b1;
if(delay_counter ==5)
begin
mode <= state3
delay_counter <= 0;
end
```

If *clk* happens every 50ns, you just created a 250ns delay. You're trapped in this state until you've met the delay, then you hop into the next state you want.

EDIT: Just reread your question and maybe I misunderstood but the concept is the same anyways. If you want *State 3* to happen 5 times you would put a block in *State 3* that points to *State 4* based on a variable counting up to 5, and *State 4* just sends you back to *State 3* or *State X* based on that variable.

Comment: I tried to use your idea for coding but still not compiling.Could you please help me !

Answer (score 0):

A *pure* FSM cannot "count" anything in the states. A counter is an FSM by itself. In order to delay `N` cycles in a specific state, you will need to expand it to `N+1` substates, which will "count" the delay transitions. Of course you can compromise the "purity" of the FSM and add a counter as you mention. You can find a plenty of examples of the code online. [Here is one example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/VHDL_for_FPGA_Design/4-Bit_Binary_Counter_with_Parallel_Load).

Comment: SO then if I want to delay it for 10 clock cycle  then I would  use the :  Case pr_state  is
When  s2 =>
nx_state <= s3

when s3=>
nx_state<= s4
 And go on like that for 10 state?

Comment: If you really want to make it pure FSM. But for large delays it will be kinda tedious and not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay in each state for the same specific amount of time, add the delay in the code that changes the current state to the next state.  Example:

```
State_Memory : Process (CLK)
begin  -- will delay changing states for 5 times the clock period
if (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
if (count = 5) then  -- 5 is max count
Current_state <= next_state;
count <=0; --reset counter
else
count<= count + 1; --increment counter
end if;
end if;
end process;
```

Comment: No, this is a problem. You will only advance to the "next_state" if count = 5. Loading the Current_state with next_state should be a separate process, or at least a separate if...else conditional. Yes, you said it was "just an example" but it is a misleading and flawed example that the OP will not be able to fix.